# Unable to autoload constant in factory girl association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a class like this

```
class SMTPProvider < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'smtp_providers'
```

And the corresponding factory for this is

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :smtp_provider, class: 'SMTPProvider' do
  end
end
```

*`FactoryGirl.create(:smtp_provider) works fine`*. But the problem is when using this in another factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :based_on, class: 'AttackPackage' do
    smtp_provider_id { FactoryGirl.create(:smtp_provider) }
  end
end
```

Here is the error

```
Unable to autoload constant SmtpProvider, expected 
/home/vamsi/code/scope2/app/models/smtp_provider.rb to define it
from /home/vamsi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
```

It's trying to load SmtpProvider, but my class name is SMTPProvider, which I have mentioned in the smtp_provider factory

Comment: What in the corresponding models code?

Comment: is your `SMTPProvider` class defined in `app/models/smtp_provider.rb` file ?, look for typos in the file name.

Comment: @MikDiet model is mentioned on the top of the post

Comment: @fanta yes it's defined exactly in the same way

Comment: have you tried using `class: SMTPProvider`(without single quotes) instead of `class: 'SMTPProvider'` ?

Comment: Yes, the error message is same @fanta

Comment: I think what you need is to define a `inflector`, try adding `config/initializers/inflections.rb` file, and there, put this code(I'll add `;` where you need a new line) `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|; inflect.acronym 'SMTP';end;`, documentation can be found here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: SMTP provider must exist
from /home/vamsi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'

Comment: that's a different error, isn't it ?, plus comments list is getting too big. So, I encourage you to check your code and see how you defined your models, that last errors seems to be a validation issue. Just to let you know, in Rails 5 all `belongs_to` associations must be present or a record will be invalid, unless you specify `optional: true`. Once again, take a look at your code, look at the backtrace and try to find where the error is coming from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146427/discussion-between-gates-and-fanta).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way RoR autoloads classes, the names you're using misalign with the autoloader. The autoloader expects there to be a `_` before every capital letter (except the first).

Right now you have a file name `smtp_provider.rb` and a class name `SMTPProvider` which mismatch. The filename for `SMTPProvider` is `s_m_t_p_controller.rb` and the class name for `smtp_provider.rb` is `SmtpProvider`

Here's a class to file name method I made to show this:

```
class String
  def upper?
    self == self.upcase
  end
end

module ClassFileName
  def self.to_file_name(class_name)
    class_name = class_name.chars
      .inject do |file_name, char|
      char = "_#{char}" if char.upper?
      file_name << char
    end.downcase
    "#{class_name}.rb"
  end
end
```

You can run it like this:

```
ClassFileName.to_file_name('SMTPProvider')
```

Which outputs: `s_m_t_p_provider.rb`

You have a few options to get them to line up:

1. create a s_m_t_p_controller.rb symlink with `ln -s app/models/smtp_provider.rb app/models/s_m_t_p_provider.rb`

   2. `mv app/models/smtp_provider.rb app/models/s_m_t_p_provider.rb` move the file entirely
   3. Rename class to `SmtpProvider` so it autoloads properly (Note: will have to update the code anywhere SMTPProvider is currently used)

I like option 3 the most since both the class and file name look "clean" to me.